# php - What is the difference between these DateTime formats?

Tags: php, symfony

What is the difference between this DateTime formats? I cannot find any details about it. Both of them should include TimeZone:

- `2019-11-28T00:00:00.000Z`
- `2019-11-28T00:00:00+00:00`

I'm using Symfony's validator as `@Assert\DateTime()` and the only second option shows as valid - why?

Comment: they are same. if your validator just accept seconds, so use first one (`2019-11-28T00:00:00.000Z`).

Answer (score 0):

They are all valid ISO 8601 date & time format.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

The first one has a decimal fraction of second (`decimal fraction` is also mentioned in the wikipedia's page: Decimal fractions may be added to any of the three time elements. ), `Z` means +00:00

So, these two DateTime formats mean the same time.

However, some frameworks (or parameters you use) can not recognize some formats, eg: the validator you used seems not supporting `decimal fraction`.

A possible reason is that one validator can only support one format. The first one has a decimal fraction which makes the format differs from the second one. If you want to support both formats, you can consider write a validator by yourself. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html#format  , https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php . There are more information about the date & time formats.